# Find the position of a certain string format in a long string

Tags: python

I want to find the position of a certain string format in a long string.
For example:

```
k='df(3)srer(2)q3r32341v(144)df'
```

I want to find the position of the string '(number),' in this case, the position of (3) and (2)

I hope the return result is

```
[2,9]
```

I wanted to use the

```
a=[]
a.append(k.find('(\d)'))
```

But it didn't work; please help me!
Thank you!

Comment: You have to use functions from the `re` library to perform regular expression searches. `re.finditer()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> [f.start() for f in re.finditer('\(\d\)', 'df(3)srer(2)q3r32341v(144)df')]
[2, 9]
```

Note that you need to escape parenthesis (e.g. `\(\d\)` if you want literal `(number)` because parenthesis is a special char in regex

If you want to include numbers of any size within the parenthesis, then use `\d+` which will include the position of `(144)` as well

```
>>> [f.start() for f in re.finditer('\(\d+\)', 'df(3)srer(2)q3r32341v(144)df')]
[2, 9, 21]
```